# Open and close set (Topology)

Tags: general-topology

I have an exercise about topology to do for tomorrow but I am really not sure of my answers or don't have any answer. Can you help me figure them out ? Thank you.

Let E be a non-empty bounded set of real numbers and put α = supE, and β = inf E.
Assume that α doesn't ∈ E and β ∈ doesn't E.Which of the following statements is true and which is false. In each case justify your answer.
(a) E is an open set.
(b) E is not a closed set.
(c) E is an inﬁnite set.
(d) (α, β) ⊂ E.

My answers are :
a) True since all points in E are interior points.
b) True supE or infE may be a limit point for E.
c) I don't know this.
d)False E ⊂ (α, β).

Is that correct? And what is the answer for c) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answers are as follows :

a) False. Take $E = (0, 1]\cup [2,3)$. This satisfies the hypothesis, but is not open (1 is not an interior point)

b) True. $\sup(E)$ and $\inf(E)$ are limit points (For every $\epsilon > 0$, $\alpha - \epsilon$ is not an upper bound, so ..)

c) If $E$ is finite, then $\sup(E) = \max(E)$ and so must be in $E$.

d) True, as you say.

Comment: Yes, that is what I indicated. Every neighbourhood of $\alpha$ and $\beta$ do contain points of $E$.

Answer (score 0):

You are right about b) and d). However, E is not necessarily open (think about a sequence of numbers). For c) try to figure out what happens if $E$ is finite, what would the $\sup$ and $\inf$ of $E$ be?.